# Intermediate value theorem proving a function is positive

Tags: calculus

I have a problem that I can't quite figure out

> Given two continuous functions $f,g$ such that $$f(2) = 5$$
> and
> $$\forall x\in\Bbb R\quad f(x)g(x) > 0,$$
> prove that
> $$\forall x\in\Bbb R\quad f(x)>0\text{ and }g(x)>0$$
> using the Intermediate value theorem.

I couldn't figure how to use it here. I could only guess that if $f(2) = 5$ then $5g(2) > 0$ then $g(2) > 0$ but I couldn't figure out if that's the right way to take that proof.

Comment: What does it mean for the product of the two functions to be positive? Can it be that there are points where both functions are negative? Why or why not?

Comment: It is a good step in the right direction to prove that $g$ is positive for some real number, as you did here, but to apply the IVT, you need some information about $g$ at some other real number. Hint: to get information about a function you don't necessarily have to directly try and compute its value, what happens if you *assume* that $g(x)<0$ for some $x$?

Comment: if g(x) < 0 for some x then f(x) < 0 too for that x also i figured out that there is no x such that f(x) = 0 or g(x) = 0 since f(x)*g(x) > 0 so if i know f(2) > 0 and g(2) > 0 and also i forgot to mention the problem says they are continus so they wont cross the x axis is it sounds ok ?

Comment: You seem to have the right idea, but you need to make the statement "they don't cross the x-axis" precise, and somehow use the intermediate value theorem for it to be a complete proof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that there exists a point $p$ such that (f(p) < 0). Additionally, we are given that (f(2) = 5).

By the Intermediate Value Theorem, if a continuous function takes on values of opposite signs at two points, then it must take on the value of zero at some point in between. Since $f(2) = 5$ and (f(p) = c < 0), there exists a point (q) in the interval ([2, p]) such that (f(q) = 0).

Now, let's consider the product function $f(x) \cdot g(x)$. Since $f(q) = 0$, we have $f(q) \cdot g(q) = 0$ for some (q) in the interval ([2, p]). However, we were initially informed that $(f(x) \cdot g(x) > 0)$ for every (x). This leads to a contradiction, as we have found a point (q) where the product is equal to zero.

Given that $f(2) = 5 > 0$ and  $f(x) \cdot g(x) > 0$ for every $x$, you can deduce that $g(2)>0$ as well.
And now, an identical argument can be made for $g(x)$. Assuming there exists a point $p'$ such that $g(p') < 0$. Therefore, for every real number $x$, we can conclude that (g(x) > 0).